# error while using diacritical marks in matlab code in latex

Tags: pdftex, miktex, matlab

I'm very new to latex and I'm trying to write a latex document in polish. It contains diacritical marks such as "ą" or "ś" and it all works fine until I try to add some Matlab code to the document. My code also contains polish letters (for example in plot titles) and when I'm trying to create pdf I get a message like the one bellow for every line of Matlab code that contains some polish letters

> ! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
>   See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate 
>   l.80 xlabel('częstotliwość próbkowania');

Does anyone know what to do to use a diacritical mark in Matlab code in latex? 
Here's what I use for my MatLab code:

```
\definecolor{greenMatlab}{RGB}{75,150,0}
\definecolor{stringColor}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\lstset{breaklines=true,
    framextopmargin=50pt,
    frame=bottomline,
    language=Matlab,
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{stringColor},
    commentstyle=\color{greenMatlab},
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},
    numbersep=9pt, 
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},
    emphstyle=[1]\color{blue},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you sure that Matlab code is UTF8-encoded? This is the default for LaTeX nowadays.

Comment: There is also the [listingsutf8](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listingsutf8/listingsutf8.pdf) package that can be used to display listings that contain utf8 characters.